# Nuke.Azure deploy web application

Tags: c#, azure, nuke-build

I am trying to use [Nuke.Build](http://www.nuke.build/index.html) to deploy a simple WebApp to Azure. The app itself is already created and I only want to upload a new version of it.

In azure-cli similar command is

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group Blah --src app.zip --name Blah
```

There seems to be  a nice and dedicated project for this - https://github.com/nuke-build/azure

It should be something along those lines

```
        Nuke.Azure.AzureResourceTasks.AzureResourceUpdate(s => s
            .SetName("Blah")
            .SetResourceGroup("Blah")
            //What to add here for the rest of configuration???
            );
```

But I cannot figure out what to do there. And dont really want to switch to a "StartProcess" solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adequate method would be `AzureWebappTasks.AzureWebappDeploymentSourceConfigZip`. Command-line tool wrappers are usually constructed and named to mimic the original invocation.